# How to efficiently get an adjacency list for a spherical Voronoi diagram?

Tags: python, graph, scipy, graph-algorithm, voronoi

I want to generate an adjacency list for the regions of a spherical Voronoi diagram. I am using the [SphericalVoronoi class](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.SphericalVoronoi.html) from SciPy so the only information I can use is the centers and vertices of the diagram.

The best thing I've come up with is checking for every pair of regions if they have a common vertex (`vor` is the instance of SphericalVoronoi):

```
def adjacent(vor, reg1, reg2):
    for i in vor.vertices[reg1]:
        if i in vor.vertices[reg2]: return True
    return False

adjacencies = [[] for i in range(len(vor.regions))]
for i in range(npoints):
    for j in range(i,npoints):
        if adjacent(vor,vor.regions[i],vor.regions[j]):
            adjacencies[i].append(j)
            adjacencies[j].append(i)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more efficient to find for each vertex regions it is in, and use that information to find which regions are neighbours.

Something like:

```
# Vertex - region adjacencies
vert2region = defaultdict(list)
for i, region in enumerate(vor.regions):
  for v in region:
    vert2region[v].append(i)

# Region - region adjacencies
adjacencies = defaultdict(set)  # set is important not to have same adjacency twice
for v, regions in vert2region.items():
  for r1, r2 in itertools.combinations(regions, 2):
    adjacencies[r1].add(r2)
    adjacencies[r2].add(r1)
```